# How to name a new Excel workbook automatically in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I would like to create a New workbook and name it as today's date and DE.
(Eg : 22.01.2018-DE) 
`Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "-DE"`

If the workbook is already existed or opened, then delete it or close it. Finally save the workbook. I used the code below but not working. Displaying `object defined error`. Help me

I need to rename Land-DE to 22.01.2018-DE.

```
Sub createlandDE()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.add
ActiveWorkbook.Names.add Name:=Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "-DE"
Dim path As String
Dim FSO As Object
path = "Q:\Job\Land-DE.xlsx" 'Need to rename the file here
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If FSO.FileExists(path) Then
    On Error Resume Next
        Workbooks("Land-DE").Close False 'Workbook name must automatically come here
        Kill path
        wb.SaveAs path
    Else
    wb.SaveAs path
 End If
```

Comment: You are formatting the date as `dd/mm/yyyy` when filenames cannot contain a slash (/), you should first change this to something like `dd-mm-yyyy`

Comment: but its working when i am creating new sheet. So only i tried for worksbook. But not working for workbook

Comment: have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
Sub createlandDE()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
NameValue = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & "-DE"
Dim path As String
Dim FSO As Object
delpath = "Q:\Job\Land-DE.xlsx" 'Need to name the file to delete
path = "Q:\Job\" & NameValue & ".xlsx" 'Need to rename the file here

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If FSO.FileExists(path) Then
    On Error Resume Next
        Workbooks(NameValue).Close False
        Kill delpath
        wb.SaveAs path
    Else
    wb.SaveAs path
 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with saving as:

```
Workbooks("Land-DE").SaveAs Filename:="Q:\Job\22.01.2018.xlsx"
```

Then delete the file with the old name.
To make it look better, consider saving `"Q:\Job\22.01.2018.xlsx"` as a String variable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are editing the wrong property.

I would simply use ActiveWorkbook.Name = [your desired name]

Comment: If you find a way to do something like this, write a mail to Microsoft, they would probably pay you some good money for reporting a major Excel bug. (`.Name` should be read-only).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-name-property-excel i check it here on purpose and it does not say read only. I am not at a computer now, so sorry if this is not possible

Comment: I see. I have just wrote a suggestion for improvement to the MSDN article. It is read-only. In the VBEditor library (accessed with F2) it is mentioned.